# rosmake compiler warnings

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was trying to rosmake turtlebot_apps on beagleboard and got compiler warnings like

```
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< kdl [PASS] [ 9.12 seconds ] -- WARNING: 2 compiler warnings
```

Should I really care about those warnings? Are they similar as normal compiler warnings?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10491/rosmake-compiler-warnings/) by [sunilsulania9192](https://answers.ros.org/users/748/sunilsulania9192/) on ROS Answers with karma: 224 on 2011-07-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

They are exactly the same as normal compiler warnings.

rosmake records warnings from a compile and gives you the condensed output you see.
Usually you also get an output that tells you where the logfile is that contains the compile output with the warnings to look at.

As for caring: Ideally code compiles without warnings. Otherwise it depends on the warnings itself. For ROS packages I would assume/hope that the warnings should not lead to bugs.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4